# Pass custom properties to PDE build via command line

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-pde

I'd like to customize the behavior of a PDE plugin build via commandline. To do so, I want to pass commandline flags to my custom PDE plugin build callback targets.

According to the [Eclipse PDE Build help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/pde_feature_generating_build.htm?cp=4_3_1_1), setting the `customBuildCallbacks.inheritall=true` property in `build.properties` guarantees that the `subant` task's `inheritall` parameter is set.

I modified my `build.properties` as follows:

```
customBuildCallbacks=customBuildCallbacks.xml
customBuildCallbacks.inheritall=true
foo=${bar}
```

then added a line to the `customBuildCallbacks.xml` buildfile:

```
<target name="pre.build.jars">
    <echo>Custom property: ${foo}</echo>
</target>
```

And launch the build as

```
$ ant -Dbar=baz
```

But the property is not replaced:

```
[ant.project.name/java] pre.build.jars.local:
[ant.project.name/java]      [echo] Custom property: ${foo}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `build.properties` file is not being loaded in the buildfile. Try to pass it to Ant from the command line:

```
ant -propertyfile build.properties ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `build.properties` file is located inside the PDE plug-in folder and is already read by Ant, in fact the `customBuildCallbacks.xml` buildfile is used. What's not happening is the propagation of properties from the commandline to the `build.properties`. In fact, if I set `bar=baz` in the `build.properties` above, the build correctly prints out `[ant.project.name/java]      [echo] Custom property: baz`

Comment: @claudiopro In your question, the output is `Custom property: ${foo}`. If `build.properties` was read by Ant, it would've printed it `Custom property: ${bar}`. Am I missing something?

Comment: When `build.properties` is parsed, `bar` is not set, so `foo` is blank; when the `pre.build.jars.local` target is executed, `foo` is not replaced and printed as `Custom property: ${foo}`. If I set `bar=baz`in the `build.properties` immediately before `foo=${bar}`, then its value is correctly printed `Custom property: baz`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path to the build.properties file in your build.xml property element. The documentation on the [Property Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) has some good examples.

```
 //build.xml
 <property file="build.properties"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `build.properties` file is located inside the PDE plug-in folder and is already read by Ant, in fact the `customBuildCallbacks.xml` buildfile is used. What's not happening is the propagation of properties from the commandline to the `build.properties`. In fact, if I set `bar=baz` in the `build.properties` above, the build correctly prints out `[ant.project.name/java]      [echo] Custom property: baz`

Comment: I used a simple build.xml and build.properties using the `<property file='build.properties'` element and Ant interpolated the value correctly.

Comment: Gotcha :-) The PDE build uses `subant` tasks so it's sliighly trickier than that. I haven't been able to dig deep enough into the internals to understand what's failing.